# What is a Directed Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

The structure of this puzzle is the same as JLee's Phrase™ puzzles.

Use these examples to find the rule. What is a Directed Phrase™?

| Directed Phrase™ | Not a Directed Phrase™ |
| --- | --- |
| Berry Scroll | Flavoured Pastry |
| Cassette Shop | Vinyl Retailer |
| Ballot Points | Election Votes |
| Massage Lounge | Relaxation Parlor |
| School Spirit | Educational Enthusiasm |
| Zero Sheep | Lacking Rams |
| ASCII Tutorial | Unicode Guide |
| Awful Organ | Terrible Piano |
| Erotic Makeup | Arousing Stylings |
| Looking Gallery | Ocular Display |
| Immune Barrier | Invincible Shield |
| Kinda Worried | Somewhat Hesitant |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Directed Phrase™ is one where the

> letters in the words go in the same direction on a Qwerty keyboard, either horizontally or vertically.

The Directed Phrases™

> Berry bottom to top, Scroll left to right
>  Cassette bottom to top, Shop L to R
>  Ballot bottom to top, Points R to L
>  Massage bottom to top,  Lounge R to L
>  School L to R, Spirit middle to top
>  Zero L to R, Sheep middle to top
>  ASCII L to R, Tutorial top to middle
>  Awful L to R, Organ top to bottom
>  Erotic top to bottom, Makeup bottom to top
>  Looking R to L, Gallery middle to top
>  Immune R to L,  Barrier bottom to top
>  Kinda R to L, Worried top to middle